# Point light shadowmapping woes

Tags: opengl

I'm doing point light shadow mapping and I'm tearing my hair out trying to iron out a bug.

The problem is shadows are basically "inverted" somehow, or wierdly placed. Here's five screenshots; you can approximate  where the light is by looking at the cube:

http://s23.postimg.org/um29e8tk9/image.png

http://s1.postimg.org/ftvzeta5q/image.jpg

http://s3.postimg.org/gd8ymwiqa/image.jpg

http://s18.postimg.org/k4608nvd4/image.jpg

http://s3.postimg.org/aqclpfg7m/image.jpg

I've gone through the code a multiple times and I just can't find why this is happening.

Relevant parts:

Definitions:

```
const uint32_t CUBEMAP_NUM_FACES = 6;   // posX => negX => posY => negY => posZ => negZ

const Vec3 CUBEMAP_DIRECTION_VECTORS[CUBEMAP_NUM_FACES] = { Vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
                                                            Vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f) };

const Vec3 CUBEMAP_UP_VECTORS[CUBEMAP_NUM_FACES] = { Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
                                                     Vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) };
```

Creating FBO/texture sampler:

```
OmnidirectionalShadowmap::OmnidirectionalShadowmap(Logger& logger, const uint32_t size, const uint32_t numFaces) : mLogger(logger)
{
    GLCALL(glGenFramebuffers(1, &mFramebuffer));
    GLCALL(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFramebuffer));

    GLCALL(glGenTextures(1, &mShadowmap));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, mShadowmap));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numFaces; i++)
        GLCALL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, size, size, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0));
    GLCALL(glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, mShadowmap, 0));
    GLCALL(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0));

    GLenum fboStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fboStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Framebuffer incomplete");
        throw std::runtime_error("Framebuffer incomplete");
    }
    GLCALL(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));

    GLCALL(glGenSamplers(1, &mTextureSampler));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLCALL(glBindSampler(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_SHADOW_OMNI, mTextureSampler));
}
```

Overall alghoritm for point lights:

```
for (const RenderableLighting::PointLight& pointLight : lighting.mPointLights)
{
            // depth pass for each face
    GLCALL(glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, mFramebuffer));
    GLCALL(glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE));
    GLCALL(glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)mShadowmapResolution, (GLsizei)mShadowmapResolution));
    for (uint32_t face = 0; face < CUBEMAP_NUM_FACES; face++)
    {
        GLCALL(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + face, mShadowmap, 0));
        Mat4 lightViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(pointLight.mLightPosition, pointLight.mLightPosition + CUBEMAP_DIRECTION_VECTORS[face], CUBEMAP_UP_VECTORS[face]);
        Mat4 lightProjMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f, 1.0f, Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);
        PointLightShadowPass(renderQueue, lightProjMatrix, lightViewMatrix);      // draws all objects using the provided matrices
    }

    GLCALL(glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST));
    GLCALL(glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)mWindowWidth, (GLsizei)mWindowHeight));
    // stencil pass first to elimiate fragments that dosnt need to be lit
    mGBuffer.BindNullForDrawing();
    PointLightStencilPass(pointLight);

    mGBuffer.BindFinalForDrawing();
    mOmnidirectionalShadowmap.BindForReading();
    PointLightLightingPass(pointLight, lighting.mGamma, lighting.mScreenSize);   // final lighting pass
    GLCALL(glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST));
}
```

The depth vertex/fragment shader is very simple and just writes the depth.

Here's the point light lighting fragment shader:

```
const std::string gShadingFragmentShader = 
"#version 420                                                                                                                           

layout(std140) uniform UnifPointLight                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                       
    mat4 mWVPMatrix;                                                                                                                    
    vec4 mLightColor;                                                                                                                   
    vec4 mLightPos;                                                                                                                     
    vec4 mGamma;                                                                                                                        
    vec2 mScreenSize;                                                                                                                   

    float mLightIntensity;                                                                                                              
    float mMaxDistance;                                                                                                                 
} UnifPointLightPass;                                                                                                                   

layout (binding = 2) uniform sampler2D unifPositionTexture;                                                                             
layout (binding = 3) uniform sampler2D unifNormalTexture;                                                                               
layout (binding = 4) uniform sampler2D unifDiffuseTexture;                                                                              
layout (binding = 7) uniform samplerCube unifShadowmap;                                                                                 

out vec4 fragColor;                                                                                                                     

float VectorToDepthValue(vec3 Vec)                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                       
    vec3 AbsVec = abs(Vec);                                                                                                             
    float LocalZcomp = max(AbsVec.x, max(AbsVec.y, AbsVec.z));                                                                          

    const float f = 100.0;                                                                                                              
    const float n = 0.1;                                                                                                                
    float NormZComp = (f + n) / (f - n) - (2 * f * n) / (f - n) / LocalZcomp;                                                           

    return (NormZComp + 1.0) * 0.5;                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                       

void main()                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                       
    vec2 texcoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / UnifPointLightPass.mScreenSize;                                                                   

    vec3 worldPos = texture(unifPositionTexture, texcoord).xyz;                                                                         
    vec3 normal   = texture(unifNormalTexture, texcoord).xyz;                                                                           
    vec3 diffuse  = texture(unifDiffuseTexture, texcoord).xyz;                                                                          
    normal        = normalize(normal);                                                                                                  

    vec3 positionDiff = (UnifPointLightPass.mLightPos.xyz - worldPos);                                                                  

    float storedDepth = texture(unifShadowmap, positionDiff);                                                                           
    float visibility = 0.0;                                                                                                             
    if (storedDepth + 0.0001 > VectorToDepthValue(positionDiff))                                                                        
        visibility = 1.0;                                                                                                               

    float dist = length(positionDiff);                                                                                                  
    float attenuation = clamp(1.0 - dist*dist * (1 / (UnifPointLightPass.mMaxDistance * UnifPointLightPass.mMaxDistance)), 0.0, 1.0);   
    attenuation *= attenuation;                                                                                                         

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(positionDiff);                                                                                            
    float angleNormal = clamp(dot(normalize(normal), lightDir), 0, 1);                                                                  

    fragColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * visibility * (angleNormal * attenuation *                                                          
                UnifPointLightPass.mLightIntensity * UnifPointLightPass.mLightColor);                                                   
}
```

The lighting part itself works as expected, the shadows don't. To me it looks correct, but I don't understand why the shadows are so disjointed?

Comment: Try changing 'vec3 positionDiff = (UnifPointLightPass.mLightPos.xyz - worldPos);' to this: vec3 positionDiff = (worldPos-UnifPointLightPass.mLightPos.xyz);

Comment: Experimented with it, but almost everything is in shadow as a result

Comment: Yeesh, can you embed the images into your question next time? The linked image site is very inconvenient and included popups to download an Android app.

Comment: Nevertheless, it sounds as though the camera's orientation is wrong when you draw into the cube faces. To debug this, consider drawing your scene to a ***color*** cubemap from your camera's position. Now, sample your cubemap like you did for depth in the shadow shader, but output to `fragColor`. If everything is working, you will not notice any significant warping as you rotate the camera. If any of the faces are wrong, you will know it immediately. You could just write the depth directly to `fragColor`, but depending on scene complexity that may not give enough visual cues.

Comment: What do you mean by a color cubemap? Draw each cube face to a specific color? By the camera, do you mean the lights "camera" or the main camera?

Comment: No, draw the scene 6 times using your regular render pipeline to each of the cube faces. Do this from the position of the main camera, but using the rotation you would use when drawing the shadow maps. Your cubemap will store the scene in color rather than its depth. Now, to debug that just sample the direction from your camera to a fragment on screen (same as you would if you were going to draw shadows using the depth cubemap) and output the sampled color. If any of the cube faces are oriented incorrectly, the image on screen will warp as you rotate the camera.

Comment: OK - I will give it a try

Comment: On vacation for half a week... will post once im back

Comment: OK I tried that - it didn't look strange at all. Any other suggestions to troubleshoot this?